# Save select fields from multiple json files to new json

Tags: python, json, glob

I have been trying to save 3 fields which I select from some JSON files to a new JSON file that will contain them all. I know I am really close but the code I provided below only saves the fields from the last JSON file (it probably overwrites every other entry saved before the last). My C-like thinking prevents me from solving an issue that probably is quite simple.

Ideally it will be great if I could at every iteration the 3 fields I care about immediately after grabbing them in a new file called `output.json` in order not to waste memory but storing them and then saving them to a file. Any ideas?

```
import os
import glob
import json
import numpy
import csv
import pickle
import nltk
import math
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import PorterStemmer

stop = stopwords.words('english')
stemmer=PorterStemmer()
dic = {}
final = []

for name in glob.glob('/Users/jorjis/Desktop/test/*'):
    jfile = open(name, 'r')
    values = json.load(jfile)
    jfile.close()
    data = values['article']['body']
    data = data.split('\n\n')
    desc = values['article']['description']
    title = values['article']['title']
    final.append(data)
    dic={'title': title, 'description': desc, 'paragraphs': data}

# get json string from that dictionary
json=json.dumps(dic)
print json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you were pretty close - you were appending variable `data` instead of `dic` to the `final` list, and converting only `dic` to json. Check the last 5 lines in snippet below to note changes.

```
import os
import glob
import json
import numpy
import csv
import pickle
import nltk
import math
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import PorterStemmer

stop = stopwords.words('english')
stemmer=PorterStemmer()
dic = {}
final = []

for name in glob.glob('/Users/jorjis/Desktop/test/*'):
    with open(name, 'r') as jfile:
        values = json.load(jfile)
    data = values['article']['body'].split('\n\n')
    desc = values['article']['description']
    title = values['article']['title']
    dic={'title': title, 'description': desc, 'paragraphs': data}
    final.append(dic)

# get json string from that dictionary
jsondata = json.dumps(final)
print jsondata
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot, that works! May I ask you if you have in mind a way to save directly the data to a JSON file instead of appending them first to final @ final.append(dic)? I am only asking as I have to process half a million JSONs and it will be great not to store them in memory.

Comment: @Swan87 Half a million is huge! Are you sure json is the right format to save this humongous amount of data? As a single json containing all that data, it won't be possible - you will need to first make the whole structure and only then can you write it to file. Check documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage).

Comment: @Swan87 I think you should ask a separate question for your new query, I've answered your original question. Don't forget to accept and upvote if my answer helped :)